# Count the frequency of matrix values including 0

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, vector, frequency

I have a vector

```
A = [ 1 1 1 2 2 3 6 8 9 9 ]
```

I would like to write a loop that counts the frequencies of values in my vector within a range I choose, this would include values that have 0 frequencies
For example, if I chose the range of `1:9` my results would be

```
3 2 1 0 0 1 0 1 2
```

If I picked `1:11` the result would be

```
3 2 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 0
```

Is this possible? Also ideally I would have to do this for giant matrices and vectors, so the fasted way to calculate this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at [histcounts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)? Particularly with the `edges` parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative suggestion to `histcounts`, which appears to be ~8x faster on Matlab 2015b:

```
A = [ 1 1 1 2 2 3 6 8 9 9 ];
maxRange = 11;
N = accumarray(A(:), 1, [maxRange,1])';
N =
     3     2     1     0     0     1     0     1     2     0     0
```

Comparing the speed:

```
K>> tic; for i = 1:100000, N1 = accumarray(A(:), 1, [maxRange,1])'; end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.537597 seconds.

K>> tic; for i = 1:100000, N2 = histcounts(A,1:maxRange+1); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 4.333394 seconds.

K>> isequal(N1, N2)
ans =
     1
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the loop request, here's a looped version, which should not be too slow since the latest engine overhaul:

```
A = [ 1 1 1 2 2 3 6 8 9 9 ];
maxRange = 11; %// your range
output = zeros(1,maxRange); %// initialise output
for ii = 1:maxRange
    tmp = A==ii; %// temporary storage
    output(ii) = sum(tmp(:)); %// find the number of occurences
end
```

which would result in

```
output = 
       3     2     1     0     0     1     0     1     2     0     0
```

Faster and not-looping would be [@beaker's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104836/count-the-frequency-of-matrix-values-including-zero-in-matlab#comment61751908_37104836) to use [`histcounts`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html):

```
[N,edges] = histcounts(A,1:maxRange+1);
N =

     3     2     1     0     0     1     0     1     2     0
```

where the `+1` makes sure the last entry is included as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input `A` to be a sorted array and the range starts from `1` and goes until some value greater than or equal to the largest element in `A`, here's an approach using `diff` and `find` -

```
%// Inputs
A = [2 4 4 4 8 9 11 11 11 12]; %// Modified for variety
maxN = 13;

idx = [0 find(diff(A)>0) numel(A)]+1;
out = zeros(1,maxN); %// OR for better performance : out(maxN) = 0;
out(A(idx(1:end-1))) = diff(idx);
```

Output -

```
out =
     0     1     0     3     0     0     0     1     1     0     3     1     0
```

Comment: seems to be slightly slower than using `accumarray`, and the sorting requirement is quite restrictive..

Comment: @nirvana-msu Could you try with `out(maxN) = 0;` too? Would be nice to see that hackish thing to play.

Comment: Yeah, that was the way I tried. Feel free to time on your Matlab installation to compare.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very easily with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Let the data be

```
A = [ 1 1 1 2 2 3 6 8 9 9 ]; %// data
B = 1:9; %// possible values
```

Then

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), B(:).'), 1);
```

gives

```
result =
     3     2     1     0     0     1     0     1     2
```

Comment: Nice one, but that's still roughly 2x slower than using `accumarray` - try timing it.

Comment: @nirvana-msu You are right, `accumarray` is faster here. Nice answer BTW